# Swift: How to prevent navigation to Google Maps when a user presses on the Google logo on Google Maps

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am using Google map framework to display map. How to prevent navigation to Google Maps when a user presses on the Google logo on Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `info.plist` and **remove** the second item (the one that has the value of 'comgooglemaps').

[image]

Google Maps uses this URL scheme to navigate to Google Maps when the logo is pressed. Since this is an optional behavior, you can safely delete it.